# Can't get EventAggregator working with AutoFac in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, mediatr, eventaggregator

I have a need for a simple EventAggregator in my ASP.NET MVC application where I'm using AutoFac. I've had a look at https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.MessageHub - I really like the simplicity and lightweight as I feel a complete service bus implementation might be overkill for my needs. But I'm all ears if someone has a better approach :)

However - I can't seem to get the setup to work with my web application. I have a very simple setup:

**HomeController (just to initiate the call)**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPublishStuffService _publishStuffService;
        private readonly IMessageHub _hub;

        public HomeController(IPublishStuffService publishStuffService, IMessageHub hub)
        {
            _publishStuffService = publishStuffService;
            _hub = hub;

            _hub.RegisterGlobalHandler((type, eventObject) => Debug.WriteLine($"Type: {type} - Event: {eventObject}"));
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            _publishStuffService.PublishStuff("Hello world");
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**The PublishStuffService**

```
public class PublishStuffService : IPublishStuffService
    {
        private readonly IMessageHub _hub;

        public PublishStuffService(IMessageHub hub)
        {
            _hub = hub;
        }

        public void PublishStuff(string message)
        {
            _hub.Publish(message);
        }
    }
```

**SubscribeToStuffService**

```
public class SubscribeToStuffService : ISubscribeToStuffService
    {
        private readonly IMessageHub _hub;

        public SubscribeToStuffService(IMessageHub hub)
        {
            _hub = hub;
            _hub.Subscribe<string>(HandleSubscription);
        }

        public void HandleSubscription(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("===================");
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
            Debug.WriteLine("===================");
        }
    }
```

My GlobalHandler prints out the message "Hello world" fine - but my subscribing service never gets called. I'm figuring it might be a problem with my AutoFac setup - but I'm unsure how to handle the situation.

My AutoFac configuration (using AutoFac.MVC5) looks like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);

builder.RegisterModelBinders(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

// Register individual components
builder.RegisterType(typeof(SubscribeToStuffService)).As<ISubscribeToStuffService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(PublishStuffService)).As<IPublishStuffService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MessageHub)).As<IMessageHub>().SingleInstance();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to ensure that the message hub is persisted across my entire web application so that I can have different classes subscribe to different events published to the message hub.
Basically I'm looking for the Notification part of Jimmy Bogards Mediatr library - which works perfect by the way - but I feel that the implementation of Mediatr might be a bit much if I only intend to use the Notification setup :)

**UPDATE**
I can actually get the subscriber events to fire if I add a dependency to ISubscribeToStuffService in the same place as I publish (here in my HomeController):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPublishStuffService _publishStuffService;
        private readonly IMessageHub _hub;
        private readonly ISubscribeToStuffService _subscribeToStuffService;

        public HomeController(IPublishStuffService publishStuffService, IMessageHub hub, ISubscribeToStuffService subscribeToStuffService)
        {
            _publishStuffService = publishStuffService;
            _hub = hub;
            _subscribeToStuffService = subscribeToStuffService;
        }
        ...
    }
```

This apparently resolves the subscriber. But that's not really helpful as it defeats the purpose of have a loose coupling between my dependencies.

So the question becomes - how do I get AutoFac to resolve my subscribers without having to add them as dependencies everywhere I publish something to the message bus? Can this be done?

**UPDATE 2**
Found this nifty little pub/sub extension for AutoFac: https://github.com/jonstelly/AutofacEvents. It does everyting I need right out of the box in terms of getting an event aggregator up and running with AutoFac.

Comment: There's some missing info here. I've never used EventAggregator, but you're not showing folks where the `ISubscribeToStuffService` is actually being consumed/instantiated. From this... it doesn't look like it ever gets used, and if it's never instantiated (and, I'd assume, alive when the message is published) then it's not going to respond to the event, right? Maybe? Again, I'm no EventAggregator person so probably can't help here.

Comment: The idea is to not create a tight coupling between the different parts of the application. So basically the message hub / service bus (what ever you would call it) should hold the information about the events being published to it - and then the subscribers should automatically get called - without having to consume them. 
So basically I could have several different actions take place when an event occurs (e.g. on the "User created" event I might want to send a welcome e-mail to the user as well as a notification to accounting). 
But I can't get the subscribers to hook up with AutoFac :(

Comment: @TravisIlligbut you're correct in the outcome (and probably also the reason) - the ISubscribeToStuff (an any other subscribers) doesn't seem to be "alive" or initiated. But I'm guessing that's because I haven't setup my IoC correct for this to work (or someone else might have a better suggestion).

Comment: This is an app design question, not IoC. It's not Autofac responsibility to figure out how or when your subscribers need to be instantiated - that's app code. When you need the instances from your app code - that's IoC.